# How to find lines in a text file containing specific strings and replace each whole line with a new string,?

Tags: java, android, string, replace

Just starting out with Java on Android.
Finding lots of example code to search for strings and replace them or remove the line where they occur.

But nothing to replace the whole line the strings occur on with a new string.

If there is an example I would be grateful for a pointer to it or some example code I can modify.

The file is never more than 50 lines.

There will always be two strings searched for and the line each occurs on will always be replaced with a completely new string.

Each string will only occur once in the file (though there are possibly some similar).

The line number is unknown (as is the text for the rest of the line).

The new line must be inserted into the text file at exactly the same line number as the original line.

Example where the text file is named: xyz-colors.txt

Search string one: yellow-XXc

New string to replace the complete line where string one occurred: John - black-XXe - new pin 13762

Search string two: green-BBa

New string to replace the complete line where string two occurred: Mike - red-XXd - new pin 14862

Thank you for any pointers.

Edit:

I have just about given up on this. So many examples but all find multiple occurrences of the string and this will be wasting resources and time, as I know for definite that there is only one occurrence. I will just ask them to restructure their files so I now the line number I need to replace and then go from there.

Edit2:
The files cannot be restructured so I have to find an alternative to Paths.get

Edit3:
I have just about resolved this.
Using Scanner to get the line number and BufferedReader and FileReader/readline to get the full string for that line number. Now I just have to replace the string from the full line with another string containing the changes using FileWriter. I will post the full code when I am finished.

Answer (score 0):

Let us approach it like this:

- You have a file to read --> Figure out how to load it first
- You have to update a file --> Figure out how to update a file.
- Read all lines (Since it is max 50, shouldnt care about optimizations here)
- Loop over each line, check if it contains the string you are searching for, replace Line with new Line.
- Loop finished? Update your file, with updated list of Lines.

Look into using File.readAllLines() from Java >= 8

Some helpfull document for you: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/3-ways-to-read-file-line-by-line-in.html#axzz6dg6HEon1

Comment: Thanks you Susan. I am trying to follow this. I can now read the file without issue using scanner and am now moving to next part.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example as a starting point without exception handling:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //path to your file
        String filename ="C:\\Temp\\xyz-colors.txt";
        //read content of file to list
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));

        String searchOne = "yellow-XXc";
        String replacementOne = "John - black-XXe - new pin 13762";

        String searchTwo = "green-BBa";
        String replacementTwo = "Mike - red-XXd - new pin 14862";

        list.replaceAll(s -> s.contains(searchOne) ? replacementOne : s);
        list.replaceAll(s -> s.contains(searchTwo) ? replacementTwo : s);

        //write modified list to file
        Files.write(Paths.get(filename), list, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So I call the method and it is expecting me to pass an argument but I cannot see what it expects to be passed. If I remove the String[] args and call the method this way then it takes me back to the login screen of my app. In debug it correctly shows the file path for List<String>. But then goes no further (crashes out to my login screen). I guess because I removed the argument. How do I call the method correctly (what is the argument I need to pass)? Thanks

Comment: @Anabelle2020  He is just showing you an example code inside the main method.  The main method is the entry point in Java, you shouldnt touch its signature/parameters.   You should create a class

Comment: Thank you Susan. I have created the new class and method now. It still throws me out to my logon screen. Is this maybe because I am running this on Android?

Comment: I have tried this with other similar examples and Paths.get is the problem. Whenever this is run it causes my app to go back to the logon screen. Yet the same path when used with Scanner(filename) or new File() work without issue so the actually path is good, just not with Paths.get!